# Is CanExecuteChanged a event property of ICommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand

Is CanExecuteChanged a event property of ICommand? If it's a property why does it have a add and remove instead of get , set?

If , it's not a property , then what is it?

```
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
```

And when does CanExecuteChanged gets fired?

Comment: It's an event. Says so right there on the title. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) to the resque!

Comment: No it is not. It is an event.

See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634777/what-is-the-actual-task-of-canexecutechanged-and-commandmanager-requerysuggested

and also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531360/what-is-canexecutechanged-for

Comment: its an event and it need some add and remove listners. that why we have this property.

Answer (score 1):

`CanExecuteChanged` is an `event` as indicated by the key word. You can read something about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The syntax of its accessor declaration is only similar to the implementation of a property.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Event and does get fired if CanExecute method changes.

There are other questions here on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531360/what-is-canexecutechanged-for#) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425923/canexecutechanged-event-of-icommand#) that might be interesting for you.