# MVVM ICommand and delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I read a [MVVM tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_view_viewmodel_communication.htm) and I got lost in the Commands part.

```
using System; 
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMDemo { 

   public class MyICommand : ICommand { 
      Action _TargetExecuteMethod; 
      Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

      public MyICommand(Action executeMethod) {
         _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod; 
      }

      public MyICommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod){ 
         _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
         _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod; 
      }

      public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() { 
         CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
      }

      bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter) { 

         if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null) { 
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod(); 
         } 

         if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null) { 
            return true; 
         } 

         return false; 
      }

      // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime 
         is longer than lifetime of UI objects that get hooked up to command 

      // Prism commands solve this in their implementation public event 
      EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

      void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) { 
         if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null) {
            _TargetExecuteMethod(); 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

I'm not understanding the purpose of the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method and the line `EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };`.
I read that EventHandler is a delegate, but what kind of delegate is it?
What does the `delegate { };` statement return?

Comment: Purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425923/canexecutechanged-event-of-icommand

Comment: Usually your `UI` elements like `Button`s with defined `Command`s will call `canExecute` method. This will stop them from throwing `NullReferenceException`. That's why the canExecuteChanged is defined as an empty delegate. try it yourself and see if you can see any exception with a simple `Button`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your second question, yes `EventHandler` is delegate of type `void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)`. The following line is an default(Empty) anonymous delegate assigned to the EventHandler. May be to prevent `NullReferenceException`. Below line can also be written as:

```
EventHandler canExecute = delegate { };
```

To get the understanding of the usage of `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` read this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531378/881798

**Update - (by @Will)**

RaiseCanExecuteChanged can be called by the code in the view model when the ability of the command to be executed has changed. For example, the save button returns false when UserName and Password are empty, but when they are filled, the VM calls RaiseCanExecuteChanged, and when the button asks the command if it can fire, it now responds in the positive.

Comment: Psst, RaiseCanExecuteChanged can be called by the code in the view model when the ability of the command to be executed has changed.  For example, the save button returns false when UserName and Password are empty, but when they are filled, the VM calls RaiseCanExecuteChanged, and when the button asks the command if it can fire, it now responds in the positive.

Comment: Very well explained. +1.

Comment: (psst, you can add that to your answer to make it complete :)